# Oracle Sequence mismatch

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have five different schemas that use the same sequence in the code from the Main Schema. 
The code is schema by schema and never overlaps.

By the end of all the schema programs, the sequence should never overlap as it runs individually.

But it is getting duplicate for one schema:

```
select min(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID), max(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID) From dmfuser_ame.MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL;
282 950 868
288 967 925

select min(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID), max(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID) From dmfuser_bts.MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL;
288 967 926
289 773 677
```

This duplicated:

```
select min(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID), max(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID) From dmfuser_mot.MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL;
**289 773 678
311 239 253**

select min(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID), max(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID) From dmfuser_riv.MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL;
289 773 678
290 761 583

select min(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID), max(FUTURE_RETAIL_ID) From dmfuser_wes.MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL;
290 761 584
290 826 644
```

What could be the possible error with this?

Edit:
Here is how the table is populated for each schema: Insert via a PLSQL code

```
 select /*+ PARALLEL(il,8) */
        rpm_future_retail_seq.NEXTVAL       future_retail_id,
        im.item,
        im.dept,
        im.class,
        im.subclass,
        rzl.loc_type                        zone_node_type,
        rzl.location,
        TRUNC(im.create_datetime)           action_date,
        il.selling_unit_retail              selling_retail,
        loc.currency_code                   selling_retail_currency,
        il.selling_uom,
        il.multi_units,
        il.multi_unit_retail,
        loc.currency_code                   multi_unit_retail_currency,
        il.multi_selling_uom,
        il.selling_unit_retail              clear_retail,
        loc.currency_code                   clear_retail_currency,
        il.selling_uom                      clear_uom,
        il.selling_unit_retail              simple_promo_retail,
        loc.currency_code                   simple_promo_retail_currency,
        il.selling_uom                      simple_promo_uom,
        0                                   on_simple_promo_ind,
        0                                   on_complex_promo_ind,
        0                                   lock_version,
        im.item_parent,
        im.diff_1                           diff_id,
        rzl.zone_id,
        'IL'                                max_hier_level,
        'IL'                                cur_hier_level
   from mig_item_master im,
        (select wh as location,
                currency_code,
                0 as type
           from mig_wh) loc,
        mig_item_loc il,
        rpm_zone_location rzl --required to use RMS migrated table as its the only one with the WH
  where il.item      = im.item
    and il.loc       = loc.location
    and rzl.location = loc.location
    and item_level   = tran_level
    and rzl.loc_type = 2
    and sellable_ind = 'Y'
    and il.loc_type  = 'W'
    and not exists (select 1
                      from mig_rpm_future_retail rfr
                     where rfr.item     = il.item
                       and rfr.location = il.loc);
```

Comment: if your DB version is 12c+, then try to set sequences as default for FUTURE_RETAIL_ID column such as `alter table MIG_RPM_FUTURE_RETAIL modify FUTURE_RETAIL_ID default seq_myid.nextval`

Comment: How are you using this sequence? That is, how you defined the default for each schema?

Comment: It's actually an PLSQL code that is executed for each schema.. updated that code in the question

Comment: Given that your question relates to the usage of the sequence you really should include the all the relevant DDL for `rpm_future_retail_seq`.

Comment: How is it that your demo queries select 2 columns (1 min value and 1 max value) but the result set has 3 columns? Methinks you are not showing reality.

Comment: It's not three columns.. it's two, placed vertically